# How to deploy custom ami with chef-solo?

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-solo

I have been working on a project with chef-solo. I need to deploy several CentOs servers with custom application on EC2. Can anyone tell me if this possible with chef or on OpsWork framework?

Thanks

Comment: Please let me know if you're question was appropriately answered.

Answer (score 0):

#### Chef: Yes

Chef is capable of managing one or more machines. Chef supports many distros, including CentOS.

#### OpsWorks: Yes (on Amazon Linux or Ubuntu), No on all others (as of April 2013)

OpsWorks is a management layer which uses Chef and generally has the same basic functionality (plus more goodies from AWS to help you manage your fleet of servers from the OpsWorks management console).

OpsWorks does not support CentOS (yet). It's still a new service so it's possible (and likely if you believe public speculation) the list of supported OS & Applications will grow.

http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/faqs/

> Q: What operating systems does AWS OpsWorks support?

AWS OpsWorks currently supports Amazon Linux and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Both operating systems are supported and maintained by AWS and are designed to provide a stable, secure, and high performance execution environment.